# Trouble getting automysqlbackup to keep connection to mysql server

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql5.1

I am trying to follow the instructions from the following page to set up backups for mysql. 
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/mysql-incremental-backup-point-in-time-recovery/
However, once I get to the step where I run the automysqlbackup, I always get this error.
ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 1: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
It seems that despite this error, some backup files are generated. However, I can't seem to figure out exactly what is causing mysql to drop the connection. I have tried to increasing the max_allowed_packet to 64M, as well as setting up the max_connections to 1000, key_buffer to 32M, max_allowed_packet to 32M and thread_stack to 512K to no avail. Has anyone else experienced this issue and figured out a way around it? Or is it even an issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are tons of things that can cause dropped connections. One that I ran into is your innodb_buffer_pool needs to be like 4x the size of max_allowed_packet (not 1x like the documentation says) for 5.1 and 5.5.

Comment: Thats just one of several potential causes. In general if your client does something mysql can't handle your connection will drop. You also need to set connection logging by setting. I think you can enable connection logging with log_error_verbosity=3 or something like that - I don't actually have access to a specific server anymore so I can't check. You can enable error logging level 3 in 5.5+ without a restart. Also read the official documentation for connection errors:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/communication-errors.html